# $\lim \limits _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^3 e^{\frac {x^4}{4}} - {\sin^{\frac 3 2} {x^2}} }{x^7}$ evaluation using expansion series

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim \limits _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^3 e^{\frac {x^4}{4}} - {\sin^{\frac 3 2} {x^2}} }{x^7}$$
This is the limit which I got from the book of **Joseph Edwards' Differential Calculus for Beginners** the second exercise of the First Chapter Page -10 question number 19. Whose Answer was given as $\frac 1 2$.

So my try was as follows:
$$\lim \limits _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^3 e^{\frac {x^4}{4}} - {\sin^{\frac 3 2} {x^2}} }{x^7}$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim \limits _{x \rightarrow 0} [ \frac{x^3(1 + \frac{x^4}{4} + \frac{x^8}{32}...) - (x^2 - \frac{x^6}{3!} + \frac{x^{10}}{5!}...)^{\frac 3 2} }{x^7} ]$$

Now, this is the quite a big problem, as we can see that sine expansion series has the power $\frac 3 2$ which is nearly impossible to evaluate.

The expansion series given in the book are: $(1+x)^n$ and $(1-x)^{-n}$ which are not useful here as there are infinite series where those are 2-terms.

Please anyone help me , I've just started Calculus :P

Comment: Generalized binomial expansion is the way to go just as for $\sqrt{1+x}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I don't know Binomial Expansion for infinite series in the book nor there is one If I know, because Binomial stands for 2 terms but there are infinite terms, so any help here is appreciated!

Comment: Group terms into a lump and use the classical binomial expansion.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Can you show by grouping a few terms?

Comment: Consider $\sqrt{1+x+x^2+x^3}$. Let $t=x+x^2+x^3$ So expand $\sqrt{1+t}$. When done, replace in the result $t$ by $x+x^2+x^3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. By using little-o notation you may control the expansions in a better way. We have that as $x\to 0^+$,
$$\frac{x^3(1 + \frac{x^4}{4} + o(x^4)) - (x^2 - \frac{x^6}{3!} + o(x^6))^{\frac 3 2} }{x^7}=\frac{1 + \frac{x^4}{4} + o(x^4) - (1 - \frac{x^4}{3!} + o(x^4))^{\frac 3 2} }{x^4}$$
Now all you need is that $(1+t)^{3/2}=1+\frac{3t}{2}+o(t)$ this can be shown by verifying that, 
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(1+t)^{3/2}-1}{t}=
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(1+t)^{3}-1}{t((1+t)^{3/2}+1)}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{3+o(1)}{((1+t)^{3/2}+1}=\frac{3}{2}.$$

Comment: I don't want to use L'Hospital, for exam-related purposes :3 XD :P

Comment: I see. Read my edit for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\lim \limits _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^3 e^{\frac {x^4}{4}} - {\sin^{\frac 3 2} {x^2}} }{x^7}{=\lim \limits _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{\frac {x^4}{4}} - \left({\sin x^2\over x^2}\right)^{3\over 2} }{x^4}\\=\lim \limits _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{\frac {x^4}{4}} -1+1- \left({\sin x^2\over x^2}\right)^{3\over 2} }{x^4}\\=\lim \limits _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{\frac {x^4}{4}} -1 }{x^4}+\lim \limits _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1 - \left({\sin x^2\over x^2}\right)^{3\over 2} }{x^4}}$$the latter equality is true since $\lim \limits _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{\frac {x^4}{4}} -1 }{x^4}={1\over 4}$ is bounded. It remains to show that $$\lim \limits _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1 - \left({\sin x^2\over x^2}\right)^{3\over 2} }{x^4}={1\over 4}$$This is  straight forward since $$\lim \limits _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1 - \left({\sin x^2\over x^2}\right)^{3\over 2} }{x^4}{=\lim \limits _{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{1 - \left({\sin u\over u}\right)^{3\over 2} }{u^2}\\=\lim \limits _{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{1 - \left({\sin u\over u}\right)^{3\over 2} }{u^2}{1 + \left({\sin u\over u}\right)^{3\over 2} \over 1 + \left({\sin u\over u}\right)^{3\over 2} }\\={1\over 2}\lim \limits _{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{1 - \left({\sin u\over u}\right)^3 }{u^2}\\={1\over 2}\lim \limits _{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{u^3-\sin^3 u }{u^5}\\={1\over 2}\lim \limits _{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{u^3-\left(u-{u^3\over 6}\right)^3 }{u^5}\\={1\over 2}\lim \limits _{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\left(1-{u^2\over 6}\right)^3 }{u^2}\\={1\over 2}\lim \limits _{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{{u^2\over 6}\left(1+\left(1-{u^2\over 6}\right)+\left(1-{u^2\over 6}\right)^2\right) }{u^2}\\={1\over 2}\lim_{u\to 0}{{3u^2\over 6}\over u^2}\\={1\over 4}}$$hence the result.

Comment: But, the answer is $\frac 12$

Comment: Sorry. You were right :)

Comment: That's Great, I was thought this was not possible without expansion, you made things go next level.... Awesome answer anyways...

Comment: Can you suggest some good books for Limits Btw...

Comment: Thank you so much. I can suggest you https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-7th-James-Stewart/dp/0538497815 . I'm not sure whether this or another version of it contains some discussions on limits (I have long before passed the courses :)  and I can't remember the references)